# Is the idiomatic way to create a Go struct field "alias" just a custom getter?

Tags: go, struct

I'm porting some Python code to Go, in an effort to learn the language. One of the things that's done in the python code is properties on class attributes that provide different aliases for member access. For example:

```py
class Grid:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def row(self):
        return self.y

    @property
    def column(self):
        return self.x

# Usage:
a = Grid(5, 7)
a.row == a.y      # True
```

This allows the user to choose which representation (`(row, column)` vs `(x, y)`) makes the most sense for a particular piece of code.

When porting this class to Go, the most obvious solution is a struct:

```golang
type Grid struct {
    X, Y int
}
```

Main question: If I wanted to create field "aliases" for a struct, is the idiomatic way to just create getters? Or is there something else built into the language that I'm not aware of?

I have found something called [struct tags](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-struct-tags-in-go) I thing that's intended to solve a different problem.

Using getters:

```golang
type Grid struct {
    X, Y int
}

func (g *Grid) Row() int {
    return g.Y
}

func (g *Grid) Column() int {
    return g.X
}

// Usage
func main() {
    g := Grid{5, 7}
    fmt.Println("%d", g.Row())
}
```

Comment: Getters like this are "okay", especially since they're likely to be expanded in line and thus not cost anything at runtime—well, except cognitive load in the reader, who might wonder why setting X changes the Column. But in general Go doesn't try to provide sixteen ways to do something. (Neither did Python originally: @property came along after many years.)

Comment: You should seriously ask, does having multiple names for the same thing make it more or less clear? And could you accomplish the same thing with a good documentation comment? Anyway, getters like this are the most appropriate option in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have another problem underlying this which is making it seem like you need aliases to clarify in different contexts.  That problem is that your naming of your data type is flawed and leads to bad assumptions.

**What is a grid?**
You mention Grid, X, Y, row and column, so let's use a spreadsheet as an example.

The spreadsheet organizes your data into a layout rows and columns.  So what is a grid? *the grid is the entire thing*.

Given this understanding of what a grid is, when we see `grid.X`, and it is an `int`, how should we assume what it means?  My assumption would be that it associates with the span of the grid on the x axis, a.k.a the number of columns.  However you've aliased this as `column` (singular)... something's not adding up.

In the context of a **grid**, a pair of a singular row and a singular column associate with a **cell**.

Hence, your naming issue would be solved better by renaming your struct:

```golang
struct Cell {
    X, Y int
}
```

Or perhaps

```golang
struct Cell {
    Row, Col uint
}
```

(I've made them `uint` here, as negative row / column numbers are typically not a thing).

The idiomatic thing to do here is not to make aliases, but to simply pick whatever names are most representative of what the data is, and how it's used.  While both naming options are pretty similar, they still have subtle differences which can cause confusion when considering which option to use.  When you see two things that are nearly the same, you might think to yourself...

> I thought I wanted to get the Y value of this cell, but now I'm seeing that there's this Row() method... maybe that's what I need?  The Y value is just a raw field, but getter methods are more safe right? It's probably doing some kind of safety check.  Hold on a second, I wonder if the value is zero based on not.  Y sounds more like a coordinate that starts at zero, but usually a row number starts counting at 1 doesn't it?  Wait what was I doing again?

The point being that more options to do the same thing isn't necessarily a good thing.  If you need to think of `Col` and `Row` as `X` and `Y` in a certain context, you could just do this:

```golang
x := cell.Col
y := cell.Row
```

Comment: Oh I agree - the names are not all that great. However, I'm just trying to port something in order to learn the language. Given that I'm trying to do a drop-in replacement, I have to keep the bad names and their aliases :-(   The calling code uses `Y` and `row` interchangeably, and I need to keep that until I can deprecate one.

Comment: Oh, and for reference, this is related to wafer mapping (semiconductor chips on a wafer before the wafer is diced). So `Chip` or `Die` might be suitable names. You do make a great point about the thought process when someone sees a getter.